# SQL Server cannot browse to any path

Tags: sql-server

I have a local SQL installed on drive C: and the data file of those system databases are stored on a network drive path, in this case it is AWS FSx.

When I attempt to restore a user database, I cannot browse anywhere.  As a test I made sure I gave the user account which runs SQL service a full access to C:\temp but I keep getting this error.

SQL error log and window error log shows me nothing... any idea guys?

[image]

When I attempt to run it using SQL code, it works.

[image]

Comment: Instead of navigating the path, have you tried pasting the complete path at once? SQL Server doesn't have permission on the root of drive C: so you might have trouble if trying no navigate to C: before going to the next folder.

Comment: I tried to give that but no dice...the weird thing is when I attempt to run it via code, it works.

Comment: There is no built-in navigation in the "locate backup file" window. You must provide the full path, including the file itself, along with its extension (e.g., C:\Backupfolder\Backup.bak)

Comment: Hi Mike, that's not it I think.  I have another environment where upon entering C: it let me browse the directory like a normal structure to  find the .bak file.